# Condition on $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbf{N}}$ for Dirichlet-series $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n^s}$ to converge for $Re(s) > 1$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, number-theory, convergence-divergence

I'm curious about the conditions on a sequence $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbf{N}}$ of real numbers such that the Dirichlet-series $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n^s}$ converges absolutely for $Re(s) > 1$. Clearly, this is the case if $a_n$ is bounded.

But what happens for instance if we let $a_n$ be the number of proper representations of $n$ by a given quadratic form? More generally, which condition on $a_n$ must be given in order that the Dirichlet-series $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n^s}$ converges absolutely?

Comment: It seems that you are looking for [Epstein zeta function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EpsteinZetaFunction.html).

Comment: yes, it was indeed a question arising, when I had a look at the Epstein Zeta. Namely, I wasn't able to prove that the Epstein Zeta is convergent for $Re(s) > 1$. Since the Epstein Zeta is equal to $\zeta(2s) \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{r_Q(n)}{n^s}$, where $r_Q (n)$ is the number of proper representations of $n$ by a binary quadratic form $Q$, I figured that I might be missing some condition of convergence of Dirichlet-series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Dirichlet series in general, we have the following (From Multiplicative Number Theory, I. Classical Theory by Montgomery and Vaughan):

**1.** Suppose $\sum \frac{a_n}{n^s}$ converges for some $s_0\in\mathbb{C}$, there is a number $\sigma_c \in \mathbb{R}\cup \{-\infty\}$ such that 
$$
\sum \frac{a_n}{n^s} $$
converges if $\mathrm{Re}(s)>\sigma_c$, diverges if $\mathrm{Re}(s)<\sigma_c$. We say that the Dirichlet series $\sum \frac{a_n}{n^s}$ has an abscissa of convergence $\sigma_c$.

**2.** Suppose $\sum \frac{a_n}{n^s}$ converges absolutely for some $s_0\in\mathbb{C}$, there is a number $\sigma_a \in \mathbb{R}\cup \{-\infty\}$ such that 
$$
\sum \frac{a_n}{n^s}$$
converges absolutely if $\mathrm{Re}(s) > \sigma_a$, does not converge absolutely if $\mathrm{Re}(s) < \sigma_a$. We say that the Dirichlet series has an abscissa of absolute convergence $\sigma_a$.

**3.** If $\sigma_c\geq 0$, then 
$$
\sigma_c = \limsup_{x\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\log |A(x)|}{\log x}
$$
Here, $A(x)=\sum_{n\leq x} a_n$. This might be the one you looked for.

**4.** 
$$
\sigma_c\leq \sigma_a\leq \sigma_c+1.
$$
From here, reference is [this](http://www2.math.ou.edu/~kmartin/ntii/chap4.pdf).
For Epstein zeta function, consider a positive definite quadratic form $Q$, and by your comment, 
$$
Z_Q(s)=\zeta(2s) \sum \frac{r_Q(n)}{n^s}.
$$
Denote by $R_Q(n)$ the number of ways representing $n$ by $Q$. Let $\Delta$ be the discriminant of $Q$. Then there are finitely many equivalence classes of quadratic forms with discriminant $\Delta$, say $Q_1$, $Q_2$, $\ldots$, $Q_{f}$. Let $Q$ be equivalent to $Q_1$. Then we have 
$$
r_{Q}(n)=r_{Q_1}(n) \leq \sum r_{Q_i}(n) \leq \sum R_{Q_i}(n) = w\sum_{d|n} \left(\frac{\Delta}{d}\right).$$
The expression on the far right, is a Dirichlet convolution of a constant function $f(n)=1$ and $g(n)=\left(\frac{\Delta}{d}\right)$. Since the Dirichlet series associated with $f(n)$ (The Riemann zeta function), and that with $g(n)$ (The Dirichlet L-function) are absolutely convergent for $\mathrm{Re}(s)>1$, we see that the Dirichlet series associated with $r_Q(n)$ is also absolutely convergent  for $\mathrm{Re}(s)>1$.

For easier proof that the Epstein zeta function is absolutely convergent for $\mathrm{Re}(s)>1$, we use the following:
$$
Q(x,y) = a|x + yz|^2
$$
for some complex $z \in \mathbb{C}-\mathbb{R}$.

Then by AM-GM inequality,
$$
Q(x,y) \geq c |x||y|$$
for some positive real $c$ depending only on $Q$ and $z$.

Treat the cases with one of $x$, $y$ being $0$, and none of $x$, $y$ being $0$ seperately.

Comment: great answer! thank you!

Comment: and for $\sum_n |a_n n^{-s}|$ to converge on $Re(s) >1$ the necessary and sufficient condition is that  for every $\epsilon > 0$ : $\sum_{n < x} |a_n| = \mathcal{O}(x^{1+\epsilon})$ (in over words : $a_n n^{-\epsilon}$ is bounded in mean value) @Steven